# EXC_BAD_ACCESS after dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I'm struggling to find what’s going wrong with my code. I’m trying to dismiss a UITableViewController using delegate but getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

The UITableViewController is called (modal segue) from the root view controller of my application. When the rootViewController try to dismiss the UITableViewController everything seems to be all right because the rootViewController view is presented but after a milisecond the error arise.

```
- (void) dismissFormAViewController: (FormAViewController*) vc{

[vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"complete.");
}];
```

}

- I can see the string Complete on my console.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @CarlNorum How do I get it?

Comment: I'm not an Xcode expert, sorry. It must be there somewhere.  Do you have a gdb console?  You can type `bt` there to get a trace.

Comment: the stack part would be more interesting.

Comment: I found it and I now I can see where is the problem! You're the man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typically this means that you are accessing some memory that isn't a valid object anymore,
to debug turn on [zombies](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSZombie) in your run scheme, this will give you at least the class that is being accessed... 
 Then if it is not obvious, you can back track with [malloc logging](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/01/10/using-malloc-to-debug-memory-misuse-in-cocoa/)

Comment: and by access, it could be an autorelease pool that is trying to release it after it is already released.